# How can I change the color of the buttons, after the user select the file and folders in each input. I'm using FLET / PYTHON

Tags: python, user-interface, flet

How can I change the color of the buttons after the user selects the file and folders in each input?
I'm using FLET / PYTHON

```
def pick_template_result(e: FilePickerResultEvent):
        if template_picker.result.files[0] != None and template_picker.result.files != None:
            template_path = template_picker.result.files[0].path
            print(template_path)
            return template_path
```

```
template_picker_button = ElevatedButton("Selecionar arquivo",
                                              on_click=lambda _: template_picker.pick_files(allow_multiple=False),
                                              icon=icons.UPLOAD_FILE,
                                              disabled=page.web)
```

[image]

When the user selects the file, I want the button to be a different color so that they visually know they have selected the file.

I tried to use ButtonStyle without success

Answer (score 0):

you can take advantage under **on_click** method. *on_click* method have event parameter thats have **control** attribute, control is object that trigged event (*flet.ElevatedButton* in this case), with this, you can simple add picker method nested in *on_click*. look at example:

```
import flet


def main(page: flet.Page):

    def on_click_file(event_control: flet.ControlEvent):
        def file_picker(event_picker: flet.FilePickerResultEvent):
            if event_picker.files is not None:
                event_control.control.color = 'red'
                event_control.control.update() # must update object or page

        dialog = flet.FilePicker(on_result=file_picker)
        page.overlay.append(dialog)
        page.update() 
        dialog.pick_files(allow_multiple=True)  # after page update

    button = flet.ElevatedButton('select files', on_click=on_click_file)
    page.add(button)


flet.app(main)
```

hope this can help you, sorry for my bad english.